# HTML generation problem

Tags: jquery, code-generation, html-generation

I'm trying to generate a small part of the page using jquery which is generating in the wrong matter even though the code looks solid.

```
$('#stages').html("");
    var stage = $("#stages");
    var L = $('<h2></h2>').attr('id', 'startachat').append('Who do you wish to connect to?');
    stage.append(L);
    var k = $('<table></table>').attr('id', 'chattypes');
    stage.append(k);
        var G = $('<tr></tr>');         
        k.append(G);
        var m = $('<td></td>');
        var s = $('<img />').attr({'src' : 'data/male_off.png', 'alt' : 'Male', 'class' : 'gender', 'id' : 'genderM'});
        var N = $('<td><td />').attr('id', 'chattypeorcell').append('or');
        var j = $('<td></td>');
        var D = $('<img />').attr({'src' : 'data/female_off.png', 'alt' : 'Female', 'class' : 'gender', 'id' : 'genderF'});
        var x = $('<td><td />').attr('id', 'chattypeorcell').append('or');
        var l = $('<td></td>');
        var z = $('<img />').attr({'src' : 'data/any_off.png', 'alt' : 'Anyone', 'class' : 'gender', 'id' : 'genderA'});

        G.append(m);
        m.append(s);
        G.append(N);
        G.append(j);
        j.append(D);
        G.append(x);
        G.append(l);
        l.append(z);
```

the html it generates has way to many "or" table data

output

```
<div id="stages">
  <h2 id="startachat">Who do you wish to connect to?</h2>
  <table id="chattypes">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="data/male_off.png" alt="Male" class="gender" id="genderM"></td>
    <td id="chattypeorcell">or</td><td id="chattypeorcell">or</td>
    <td><img src="data/female_off.png" alt="Female" class="gender" id="genderF"></td>
    <td id="chattypeorcell">or</td><td id="chattypeorcell">or</td>
    <td><img src="data/any_off.png" alt="Anyone" class="gender" id="genderA"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want it to generate something similar to this

```
    <div id="stages"> 
      <h2 id="startachat">What's your gender?</h2> 
      <table id="chattypes"> 
        <tr> 
            <td id="chattypetextcell"><img src="data/male_off.png" alt="Male" class="gender" id="genderM"/></td> 
            <td id="chattypeorcell">or</td> 
            <td id="chattypevideocell"><img src="data/female_off.png" alt="Female" class="gender" id="genderF"/></td> 
            <td id="chattypeorcell">or</td> 
            <td id="chattypevideocell"><img src="data/any_off.png" alt="Anyone" class="gender" id="genderA"/></td> 
        </tr> 
      </table> 
    </div>
```

thank you for reading

Comment: There are well, many problems with this...why are you generating it like this though?  Keep in mind that IDs have to be unique, you should use classes for these cells.

Comment: How can you tell this code is solid?  Frankly, the variable names suck.

Comment: @Justin Johnson, haha well I trying to save bandwidth as much on the variables as i can.

@Nick Craver, yeah i'll change them to classes and fix the CSS.

Comment: That is an incredibly premature optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closing td tag is wrong.

It should be :

```
$('<td></td>').attr('id', 'chattypeorcell').append('or');
```

instead of:

```
$('<td><td />').attr('id', 'chattypeorcell').append('or');
```

Comment: WOW, I've been suffering for like a week and never noticed that. Thanks a lot man I really appreciate it, if i turn rich of my site i'll send you some money.

Comment: BTW is there any way I could clone both "or"'s to save typing a line of jquery or thats not good anyways

Answer (score 0):

you use "chattypeorcell" as element ID, thus it should be unique, but in fact it's inserted several times, which mustn't help the DOM to be correctly generated...
i'm also wondering why you use so many DOM manipulations, there should be a more straight forward way (insert a string as HTML?).

Comment: Just trying to save bandwidth on the javascript file., Well maybe i'm not saving it i could just make it output raw html code but then again using jQuery commands is so much fun